# less import not working in react 16

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less, babeljs, antd

I have following webpack.config. all works fine, expect less import (import './some.less'). no errors, but also no change in compiled css files.
I used React 16, Babel, typescript
Any idea whats wrong here ?

```
module: {
rules: [
  {
    exclude: [
      // html-webpack-plugin
      /\.ejs$/, /\.html$/, /\.ico$/,
      // css-loader
      /\.css$/,
      // awesome-typescript-loader
      /\.json$/, /\.jsx?$/, /\.tsx?$/,
      // url-loader
      /\.svg$/, /\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/, /\.webp$/
    ],
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'media/[name].[ext]'
    }
  },
  {
    test: [/\.svg$/, /\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/, /\.webp$/],
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 8192,
      name: 'media/[name].[ext]'
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'style-loader'
      },
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: [
            require('autoprefixer')()
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
    { test: /\.less$/, loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader"]},
```

Comment: You don't seem to have an appropriate loader for `.less` files. I am guessing you do not see any error because the `.less` file are being loaded by the file loader

Comment: sorry, i didn't copied the most important part :-)
added last line

Comment: if there is no error, how do you know it's not working? do you mean antd components dont have styling? are you using babel-plugin-import with style:true?